# gethostbyaddr() returns null

Tags: c++, linux

I know this question was asked here before and I read all the answers, but wasn't able to resolve this on my own. Here's the deal:
I have to make a program which takes a bunch of internet addresses (like google.com, www.root.cz) and prints out an official name, alternative names and IP adresses and domain names of aliases.
We've got a sample code for 1 address without the aliases domain name, so I used it, then made a few changes to fit my needs. 
The code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i){
    hostent *H = gethostbyname(argv[i]);
    if (H == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Nepodařilo se zjistit adresu" << std::endl;
            return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Oficiální jméno: " << H->h_name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Alternativy: " << std::endl;
    /* Budeme procházet pole H->h_aliases. Pole je ukončené NULL.*/
        char **alternativy = H->h_aliases;
    while(*alternativy != NULL)
{
    std::cout << "\t" << *(alternativy++) << std::endl;
}
/* Budeme procházet pole H->h_addr_list. Pole je ukončené NULL. 
       Zvolíme jiný postup než v předchozím případě.*/
std::cout << "Adresy: " << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; H->h_addr_list[i] != NULL; ++i)
    {
        /* H->h_addr_list je binární forma IP adresy. Pro převod na
           tečkovou konvenci použijeme inet_ntoa.*/
const char* addr = inet_ntoa(*(in_addr *)H->h_addr_list[i]);
hostent *name = gethostbyaddr(addr, sizeof(addr), AF_INET);
std::cout<<addr<<"->"<<name<<std::endl;
}
std::cout<<std::endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine. Only name is always null. I tried running this on ubuntu 12.04 I have on my laptop and on virtual Debian Squeeze(don't remember number). I checked some of the config files as stated in previous questions. Also tried configuring more DNS servers. Nothing works. 
I also tried using getnameinfo, but for some reason it always returned only given IP address. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the `hostent*` `NULL` or is the `h_name` field `NULL`?

Comment: There’s no need (and indeed it’s discouraged) to add the tags to the title. Ideally, the title should form a (more or less) grammatical, concise sentence

Comment: On the same system, from the command line if you run `host <hostname>` and then `host <ip address>` do you get an answer from both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing wrong format of IP that you want to translate back to hostname.

Change your for like this.

```
for(int i = 0; H->h_addr_list[i] != NULL; ++i)
{
    /* H->h_addr_list je binární forma IP adresy. Pro převod na tečkovou konvenci použijeme inet_ntoa.*/
    const char* addr = inet_ntoa(*(in_addr *)H->h_addr_list[i]);
    hostent *name = gethostbyaddr((in_addr *)H->h_addr_list[i], sizeof(in_addr), AF_INET);
    std::cout<<addr<<"->"<<name->h_name<<std::endl;
}
```

also look for `getaddrinfo()` because `gethotbyname(),gethostbyaddr()` are obsolete functions

Answer (score 0):

There is an error calling gethostbyaddr() with incorrect parameters (it expects a binary address, not a string), and another error displaying the returned name (which is a field of hostent). I have tried the following and seems to work fine:

```
hostent *name = gethostbyaddr(H->h_addr_list[i], sizeof (struct in_addr), AF_INET);
std::cout << addr << "->" << name->h_name << std::endl;
```